# how to map hive to elastic search _id field

Tags: hive

I want to map hive key value to elastic search _id field.

Example:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test (id BIGINT ,name string,dept string) 
STORED BY 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsStorageHandler' TBLPROPERTIES('es.resource' = 'hive/test','es.id.field' = 'id');
```

while am inserting record and checking elastic search it show below

```
{
    "_index": "hive",
    "_type": "extest",
    "_id": "AU6qODiDNN1Z0nJPsoXP",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "alex",
        "dept": "bigdata"
    }
```

`"id": 1` and  `"_id": "AU6qODiDNN1Z0nJPsoXP"` both are not sync up. I want to sync up both the values.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `es.mapping.id` property instead of your `es.id.field`.

See this link for more details:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html#cfg-mapping